# Pulling data from a Named range in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, concatenation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm wondering if this is doable in Google Sheets.
I have product and ingredient list in a named range called Goods

[image]

I want to display a summary of what ingredients are needed in one cell. For example, I want the cell to say for **2 Wheat, 2 carrot**.

So in natural language, I would like to look at the row, and if it has a value in it, then return that value and the header value, if it has 0 or null, I want to skip it.

Is this possible?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1PxDqUslkuHlnDbfQVzzf14--KzrUPcLV7tNbBygCat8/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

while there are various ways how to get partial ranges from Named ranges, in a long run it is more clumsy than not using Named ranges. but possible. for example to get headers:

```
=INDEX(Goods, 1, )
```

using `INDEX`, `FILTER`, `QUERY`, `OFFSET`, `ARRAY_CONSTRAIN` you can get various pieces of what you need.

---

alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(E4:P10<>"", E3:P3&" "&E4:P10, )),,999^99))))
```

[image: 0]

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(E4:P10<>"", E4:P10&" "&E3:P3&",", )),,999^99))), ",$", ))
```

[image: 0]